# Consulta sobre variables java

Tags: java

el problema es que no me deja llamar a las variables de `hora1`,`minuto1` y `segundo1` al final del método para realizar la impresión

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class menus {
    public menus(){

    }

    public void tiempo(){

        while (true) {
            String hora = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite una hora que no exceda las 24");
            int hora1 = Integer.parseInt(hora);
            if(hora1 > 24){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Las horas no pueden ser mayores a 24","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
            else{
                break;
            }
     }   

        while (true) {
            String minutos = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite los minutos que no excedan los 59");
            int minutos1 = Integer.parseInt(minutos);
            if(minutos1 > 59){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Los minutos no pueden ser mayores a 59","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
            else{
                break;
            }
     }
        while (true) {
            String segundos = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite los segundos que no excedan los 59");
            int segundos1 = Integer.parseInt(segundos);
            if(segundos1 > 59){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Los segundos no pueden ser mayores a 59","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
            else{
                break;
            }
     }  
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"La hora es:"+hora1+"con"+minutos1+ "minutos con "+segundos1+" segundos");
    }
```

Comment: Si antes de la última linea haces System.out.println("La hora es:"+hora1+"con"+minutos1+ "minutos con "+segundos1+" segundos") de las variables, salen los valores en la consola?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto sucede básicamente porque **`las variables están declaradas en el ámbito del while`**, es decir fuera de este **`no se puede acceder a ellas`** , es por eso que no puedes acceder para realizar la impresión respectiva.

Una solución sería declarar las variables a nivel de método de la siguiente forma

```
public void tiempo(){
   /* Declaración de las variables a Nivel de método*/
   int hora1,minutos1,segundos1;
   /* resto de código */
    while (true) {...
       hora1 = Integer.parseInt(hora);/* Asigna el valor a la variable*/
       /* ... */
    } 
    while (true) {...
       minuto1 = Integer.parseInt(minutos);/* Asigna el valor a la variable*/
       /* ... */
    }  

     while (true) {...
       segundos1= Integer.parseInt(segundos);/* Asigna el valor a la variable*/
       /* ... */
    }
   /* Fuera de los While , se podrá acceder a las variables*/
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"La hora es:"+hora1
           +"con"+minutos1+ "minutos con "+segundos1+" segundos");    
}
```

Comment: Te lo agradesco con tu solucion ya pude hacerlo bien